# In mongodb site there are two setups available in production release that whats nightly?

Tags: mongodb

HI, In mongodb site there are two setups available in production release.So what is nightly whats the difference between 1.6.5 and nightly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would expect the 1.6.5 one is the official build release for that version. The nightly build is most likely the nightly build for that branch of development.

If there was a bug (security issue, whatever) which was discovered in 1.6.5, it would likely be fixed (over however many days it might take), at which point the fix (which may or may not be feature-complete) would appear in the nightlies, but not yet in the final release above it. When they were happy it was ready for release, there would be a new release from the 1.6 branch (most likely `1.6.6`) and the cycle would continue until the `1.8` branch (which is currently `1.7`) replaced 1.6 as the stable GA branch. MongoDB's version numbering strategy is [explained here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Version+Numbers).

I hope that makes sense, and I believe that would most likely be what happens. Of course, if anyone is involved in MongoDB's development and wishes to correct me, feel free. :)